# Parsing value from a DIV to another DIV with AJAX or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a list of value display with PHP in a tabular form, Company Name & Company Type. Onclick of any list of Company Name it takes the ID of the list and takes to another page to use ID to query a database table to display another list. But I need help on how to display this on the same page instead of taking users to another page, it should toggle down and parse the ID of the Company Name clicked to the next DIV and reuse the ID there. Below is my code:

````
--------------------- First Div --------------------------
<div class="panel col-100">
                <div class="panelHeader">
                    <h1>Listed Companies</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="panelBody">
                    <div class="table">
                        <div class="tableHeader">
                            <div class="tr">
                                <div class="th">NO.</div>
                                <div class="th">COMPANY NAME</div>
                                <div class="th">COMPANY TYPE</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tableBody">
                            
                            
                            <?php
                                $query_active = "SELECT * FROM  `table`";
                                $result_active = mysqli_query($connLocal, $query_active);
                                if(mysqli_num_rows($result_active)){
                                    $active_numbering=0;
                                    while($row_active = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_active)){
                                        $active_numbering++;
                                        $project_id     = $row_active['project_id'];
                                        $project_name  = $row_active['project_name'];
                                        $project_type = $row_active['project_type'];
                                    ?>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class="tr">
                                        <div class="td"><?=$active_numbering;?></div>
                                        <div class="td" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#process_toggle" ><a href="activities_page.php?process_id=<?=$process_id; ?>" ><?=$project_name; ?></a></div>
                        <div class="td"><?=$project_type; ?></div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        --------- First DIV ends --------------



-------------- Second DIV Starts ---------------

<div id="process_toggle" class="collapse">

    
    <div class="panel col-100">
        <div class="panelHeader">
            <h1>Process</h1>
            <button type = "button" class = "add-new" onclick = "openAddTab('','0')">Add new</button>
        </div>
        <div class="panelBody">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="tableHeader">
                    <div class="tr">
                        <div class="th">NO.</div>
                        <div class="th">PROCESS NAME</div>
                        <div class="th"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tableBody">
<?php
    $query_process = " SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE project_id = '".$project_id."' " ;
    $result_process = mysqli_query($connLocal, $query_process);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_process)){
        $NO=0;
        while($row_process = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_process)){
            $NO++;
            $name     = $row_process['process_name'];
            $process_id     = $row_process['process_id'];
            
            
        ?>
                <div class="tr">
                    <div class="td"><?=$NO; ?></div>
                    <div class="td"><a href="activities_page.php?process_id=<?=$process_id; ?>"><?=$name?></a></div>
                    <form method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="process_id" value="<?=$process_id; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_project" value="<?=$project_id; ?>">
                    <div class="col-50-form">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit_del_process" style="background-color: red; color: white; padding-right: 50px;padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 10px"><center>DELETE</center></button>

                </div>
                
                    </form>
                </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
</div>


------------------- Second DIV ends ---------------------
    
             ```


The ID to be parse from onclick of company name is "$project_id" from first DIV to the second DIV so I can reuse the ID.
````

Comment: Sounds like using JavaScript to maintain some state, the current selected ID. And then again using JavaScript to append some HTML based off an Xhr (Ajax) response? Are you familiar with Xhr requests?

Comment: No am not familiar with it. But only with PHP, am new to Javascript and Ajax. I want to be able to parse the ID to the PHP GET["porject_id"] on the click of the text to another DIV as it open.

Comment: You might be able to accomplish this in a way that just uses PHP. But if you want to really do it without a full page reload then it sounds like you will need to strap in and begin the next chapter in your progression as a web developer... "getting around all the limitations of stateless HTTP and server side code". i.e. learning how to use JavaScript and perform Xhr requests. Really too broad to answer here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some I was able to resolve this but simply using AJAX to get the URL from the first to the second DIV.

```
-------------------- AJAX ----------------------
<script type="text/javascript">
    
$("#project_id_parse").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // <-------stop the def behavior here.
  var id = this.href.split('=').pop(); // extract the id here
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "project_list.php",
    data: {id:id}, // now pass it here
    success: function(data) {
      $('#process_toggle').html(data); //copy and paste for your special case
    }
  });
});


--------------------- First DIV -------------------------

<?php
    $query_active = "SELECT * FROM  `table`";
    $result_active = mysqli_query($connLocal, $query_active);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_active)){
        $active_numbering=0;
        while($row_active = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_active)){
            $active_numbering++;
            $project_id     = $row_active['project_id'];
            $project_name  = $row_active['project_name'];
            $project_type = $row_active['project_type'];
        ?>

<div class="td" id="project_id_parse">
<a href="project_list.php?id=<?=$project_id; ?>" >
Project Name
</a>
</div>
                    


--------------------- Second DIV -------------------------


<div id="process_toggle" >


<?php

$project_id = $_GET["id"];

echo $project_id;

?>
```

Comment: May want to point out you're using jQuery for this to avoid confusing anyone that wonders why your code doesn't work.